# Darkflow's .pb model unable to detect objects whereas the original darknet weights file is able to

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, darknet, darkflow

I'm creating a custom training model using darknet and am trying to convert the weights file generated to a tensorflow weights file using this command:

```
flow --model cfg/custom.cfg --load bin/custom.weights --savepb
```

The execution is successful and a .pb file is generated. The original weights file is able to detect objects but when I run the .pb file there is no detection.

This is the output when I run the .pb file:

```
./darknet detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/tiny-yolo-obj.cfg tiny-yolo-obj.weights pos-1.jpg --threshold 0
layer     filters    size              input                output
    0 conv     16  3 x 3 / 1   416 x 416 x   3   ->   416 x 416 x  16  0.150 BFLOPs
    1 max          2 x 2 / 2   416 x 416 x  16   ->   208 x 208 x  16
    2 conv     32  3 x 3 / 1   208 x 208 x  16   ->   208 x 208 x  32  0.399 BFLOPs
    3 max          2 x 2 / 2   208 x 208 x  32   ->   104 x 104 x  32
    4 conv     64  3 x 3 / 1   104 x 104 x  32   ->   104 x 104 x  64  0.399 BFLOPs
    5 max          2 x 2 / 2   104 x 104 x  64   ->    52 x  52 x  64
    6 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1    52 x  52 x  64   ->    52 x  52 x 128  0.399 BFLOPs
    7 max          2 x 2 / 2    52 x  52 x 128   ->    26 x  26 x 128
    8 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    26 x  26 x 128   ->    26 x  26 x 256  0.399 BFLOPs
    9 max          2 x 2 / 2    26 x  26 x 256   ->    13 x  13 x 256
   10 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x 256   ->    13 x  13 x 512  0.399 BFLOPs
   11 max          2 x 2 / 1    13 x  13 x 512   ->    13 x  13 x 512
   12 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x 512   ->    13 x  13 x1024  1.595 BFLOPs
   13 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->    13 x  13 x1024  3.190 BFLOPs
   14 conv     30  1 x 1 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->    13 x  13 x  30  0.010 BFLOPs
   15 detection
mask_scale: Using default '1.000000'
Loading weights from tiny-yolo-obj.weights...Done!
pos-1.jpg: Predicted in 0.010284 seconds.
```